# Arithmetic Operation in Java

Tags: java

Assume that I have one arithmetic function which will add two `long` variables and return a `long` value. If pass `Long.MAX_VALUE` as an argument it wont give a perfect result. What will be the solution for that? The code below explains what I mean:

```
public class ArithmeticExample {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ArithmeticExample.addLong(Long.MAX_VALUE, Long.MAX_VALUE));
    }

    public static long addLong(long a,long b){
        return a+b;
    }       
}
```

Comment: *"what will be the solution for that"* The solution for what? `long` has a range. If you add `Long.MAX_VALUE` to itself, you'll exceed that range and wrap around. So? (I'd probably look for work somewhere else, unless the interviewer had a better question than that.)

Comment: What is the expected result? Good solutions are "overflow" (that happens already), "saturate" , "widen" (although there is no wider primitive, you'd need to go to BigInteger) and "error out".

Answer (score 1):

So you can see the wood from the trees, let's recast the problem using `byte` rather than `long` and consider

```
byte a = 0b01111111; // i.e. 127, the largest value of a `byte`.
byte b = 0b01111111;
byte c = (byte)(a + b);
```

where you need the explicit cast to circumvent conversion of `a + b` to an `int`.

Computing `c` by hand gives you `0b11111110`. This is, of course, the bitwise representation of -2 in an 8 bit 2's complement type.

So the answer for the `byte` case is -2. And the same holds true for a `long`: there are just more `1` bits to contend with in your addition.

Note that although all this is perfectly well-defined in Java, the same cannot be said for C and C++.

If you need to add two `long` values of such magnitude then consider using `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

The result is -2. This is not what is expected as it seems to be more an overflow than anything else, but this result is "normal".

```
Long.MAX_VALUE = 9223372036854775807
Long.MAX_VALUE + 1 = 9223372036854775807
Long.MAX_VALUE + Long.MAX_VALUE = -2
```